# SSRS-Export ToExcel-without MS office on client

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel

SSRS Question: What will happen if a client machine does not have MS Office installed on it and a SSRS report's "Export to EXCEL/WORD" functionality produces on excel report? One possibility is the file will get saved on client machine but one can not open it in excel format. What is the solution to overcome this issue? Can we do something from server side?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - the report will export to Excel or Word, and the client would then be unable to open the file.  If you want to open an Excel file, you *will* need *something* that can read the file format.  Open source office solutions could work, as could Microsoft's Office Viewer applications, or even a converter tool that converts the file to another format.

Alternatively, could you just export to a format that IS accessible on the client machine?  CSV, tab delimited, HTML, etc?